# Align multiple lines in 'multline' command

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

```
\begin{multline}
e^{-\lambda T} = ( 1 - \log S_j^* (T))^{\frac{1}{1-\theta}} \\
- \lambda T = \dfrac{1}{1-\theta} \log ( 1 - \log S_j^*(t))  \\
T = \dfrac{1}{\lambda (\theta-1)} \log ( 1 - \log S_j^*(t)) 
\end{multline}
```

[image]

I have three lines of equations which appears like the attached image file.
I would like to center them or align to the left.
How can I do that?

Comment: use `gather` rather than `multline` ? (`multline` is intended for one long equation, which is why it starts on the left and finishes on the right)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `align`, or if you want only one number use `aligned` inside an `equation`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  e^{-\lambda T} &= ( 1 - \log S_j^* (T))^{\frac{1}{1-\theta}} \\
  - \lambda T &= \dfrac{1}{1-\theta} \log ( 1 - \log S_j^*(t))  \\
  T &= \dfrac{1}{\lambda (\theta-1)} \log ( 1 - \log S_j^*(t)) 
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    e^{-\lambda T} &= ( 1 - \log S_j^* (T))^{\frac{1}{1-\theta}} \\
    - \lambda T &= \dfrac{1}{1-\theta} \log ( 1 - \log S_j^*(t))  \\
    T &= \dfrac{1}{\lambda (\theta-1)} \log ( 1 - \log S_j^*(t)) 
  \end{aligned}  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]